# Failed to execute 'exitFullscreen' on 'Document': Document not active

Tags: javascript

I am trying exit full screen in react js, but when i try the below code its getting the error

```
Failed to execute 'exitFullscreen' on 'Document': Document not active
```

So after searching i found to use fullScreenElement check, so i wrapped it with an if condition, but currently on chrome even if i click on exit button its not performing anything.

```
function exitFull() {
    if (
      document.fullscreenElement ||
      document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
      document.mozFullScreenElement ||
      document.msExitFullscreenElement
    ) {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
      setIsFull(false);
    }
  }
```

Because when i debugged fullscreenElement is showing as null, and if i replace it with document.fullscreen its giving false and as mentioned in docs its deprectaed so that why i used fullscreenElement?

This is the snippet where i get the mentioned error when invoking this function

```
document.exitFullscreen();

Failed to execute 'exitFullscreen' on 'Document': Document not active
```

Any idea how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem，i find a reason is that exitFullscreen only can take effect when full screen mode.Otherwise you will receive a mistake: Document not active

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).